# Dealing with hex values in C/C++

Tags: c++, hex, protobuf-net

I receive values using winsock from another computer on the network. It is a TCP socket, with the 4 first bytes of the message carrying its size. The rest of the message is formatted by the server using protobuf (protocol buffers from google).

The problemn, I think, is that it seems that the values sent by the server are hex values sent as char (ie only 10 received for 0x10). To receive the values, I do this :

```
bytesreceived = recv(sock, buffer, msg_size, 0);
for (int i=0;i<bytesreceived;i++) 
{
    data_s << hex << buffer[i];
}
```

where data_s is a stringstream. Them I can use the ParseFromIstream(&data_s) method from protobuf and recover the information I want.

The problem that I have is that this is VERY VERY long (I got another implementation using QSock taht I can't use for my project but which is much faster, so there is no problem on the server side).

I tried many things that I took from here and everywhere on the internet (using Arrays of bytes, strings), but nothing works.

Do I have any other options ?

Thank you for your time and comments ;)

Comment: To clarify, you want to convert a long stream of ASCII characters in the range `[0-9A-F]` into... something? Into a stream of bytes? A stream of big-endian 4-byte ints?

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with C? It looks like C++.

Comment: A stream, an array or a string, because protobuf can handle all these things. I think the goal is to get big-endian 4-byte ints, but all this begins no to be very clear in my head ..

Comment: @Fred Larson : right. I have retagged it.

Comment: @Fred : my code is C++ because I use streams, but I would be really happy with an help involving C rather than C++ :)

Comment: Please look up about ending if machiness and the various functions for the network. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness, http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Byte-Order.html

Comment: I also added the tag protobuf-net as this seems to be closely related. @Ben, should I have made any mistake in the retagging please let me know!

Comment: Shlublu : thanks, yes indeed it is related to protobuf.

Ed : the problem is not, I think, about big and little endian, because the piece of code I posted works (and I do not do anything with the byte order). The problem is it is very very slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this will be of any use, but I've used a similar protocol before (first 4 bytes holds an int with the length, rest is encoded using protobuf) and to decode it I did something like this (probably not the most efficient solution due to appending to strings):

```
// Once I've got the first 4 bytes, cast it to an int:
int msgLen = ntohl(*reinterpret_cast<const int*>(buffer));

// Check I've got enough bytes for the message, if I have then 
// just parse the buffer directly
MyProtobufObj obj;
if( bytesreceived >= msgLen+4 )
{
  obj.ParseFromArray(buffer+4,msgLen);
}
else
{
  // just keep appending buffer to an STL string until I have 
  // msgLen+4 bytes and then do
  // obj.ParseFromString(myStlString)
}
```

Comment: Yes ! Thanks a lot. I think I was carried too far with my problem with hex and streams to see that simple solution, only using the append() method from string.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the stream operators. They're for formatted data and that's not what you want.

You can keep the values received in a std::vector with the char type (vector of bytes). That would essentially just be a dynamic array. If you want to continue using a string stream, you can use the stringstream::write function which takes a buffer and a length. You should have the buffer and number of bytes received from your call to recv.

If you want to use the vector method, you can use std::copy to make it easier.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

char buf[256];
std::vector<char> bytes;
size_t n = recv(sock, buf, 256, 0);
std::copy(buf, buf + n, std::back_inserter(bytes));
```

Comment: Thanks. I already thought of using vectors, but protobuf cannot parse them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of ambiguous. Let's follow your example. You receive `10` as characters and you want to retrieve this as a hex number.

Assuming `recv` will give you this character string, you can do this.

First of all make it null terminated:

```
bytesreceived[msg_size] = '\0';
```

then you can very easily read the value from this buffer using standard *scanf function for strings:

```
int hexValue;
sscanf(bytesreceived, "%x", &hexValue);
```

There you go!

Edit: If you receive the number in reverse order (so `01` for `10`), probably your best shot is to convert it manually:

```
int hexValue = 0;
int positionValue = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < msg_size; ++i)
{
    int digit = 0;
    if (bytesreceived[i] >= '0' && bytesreceived[i] <= '9')
        digit = bytesreceived[i]-'0';
    else if (bytesreceived[i] >= 'a' && bytesreceived[i] <= 'f')
        digit = bytesreceived[i]-'a';
    else if (bytesreceived[i] >= 'A' && bytesreceived[i] <= 'F')
        digit = bytesreceived[i]-'A';
    else // Some kind of error!
        return error;
    hexValue += digit*positionValue;
    positionValue *= 16;
}
```

This is just a clear example though. In reality you would do it with bit shifting for example rather than multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a shot into the dark: Let's say your ingress stream is `"71F4E81DA..."`, and you want to turn this into a byte stream `{ 0x71, 0xF4, 0xE8, ...}`. Then we can just assemble the bytes from the character literals as follows, schematically:

```
char * p = getCurrentPointer();

while (chars_left() >= 2)
{
  unsigned char b;
  b  = get_byte_value(*p++) << 8;
  b += get_byte_value(*p++);

  output_stream.insert(b);
}
```

Here we use a little helper function:

```
unsigned char get_byte_value(char c)
{
  if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return c - '0';
  if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') return 10 + c - 'A';
  if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') return 10 + c - 'a';

  return 0;  // error
}
```

Comment: It should be `0 <= c`, not `'0' <= c`. There is a difference!

Comment: @Nawaz: Other way round - it should have been `'9'` and not `9` :-) Thanks, I fixed it. The assumption here is that the OP is reading *text* which represents numbers hexadecimally. I may be wrong with that assumption, but that's how I understood the question.

Comment: Oh yeah. I just got confused :P

Answer (score 0):

What data type is `buffer`?

The whole thing looks like a great big no-op, since `operator<<(stringstream&, char)` ignores the base specifier.  The `hex` specifier only affects formatting of **non-character** integral types.  For certain you don't want to be handing textual data to protobuf.

Just hand the `buffer` pointer to protobuf, you're done.

Comment: That's the first thing that I tried (not exactly actually, because the message size is big I first receive the data chunk by chunk and put everything in an array). And this, for the reason I don't understand, doesn't work.

Comment: @Ben: I repeat my question: "what data type is `buffer`?"

Comment: It's a stream of bytes received from a socket. Actually you are right, I really was in the wrong direction. Still, handing the buffer pointer to protobuf doesn't work ... though it should